# Text-overflow: ellipsis not working on th element

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, ellipsis

I have this markup with `th` elements with `text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;`.

Also, the `td` and `th` is set to `display: block`.

When I put something like `width: 130px` on the `th` the text will show the ellipsis, otherwise not.

I don't know what else to put on the code so I will just post what I have until now:

```css
table {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
thead {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 30%;
}
tbody {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
td,
th {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13pt;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  border-left: 0;
}
th {
  background-color: DarkSlateBlue;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th:not(:last-child),
td:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr id="trParticipantes">
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Crispy Bacooooooooooooooooooooon</th>
      <th>Marco</th>
      <th>Filipe</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbodyTempos">
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 2</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 3</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 4</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 5</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 6</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 7</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 8</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 9</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 10</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 11</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 12</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 13</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 14</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 15</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 16</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 17</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 18</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 19</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fase 20</td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tempo" min="0" step=".1" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You have turned the <table> into a flexbox layout, what is the reason?

Comment: to get a responsive table. the tbody will scroll according to the user swipe. the thead is fixed on the left and tbody fixed to the right, each occupying 50% of the parent element width (in the example I put a scrollbar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'flex-shrink' property on your tr needs to be set to 1, otherwise it just flows out of the table into the next. The default value is 1 which tells the display to shrink x the value of other items in the box, since there is only the one item it will fill the box.